# Linux Mint 18 deletes /etc/init.d/xorg.conf on every reboot and fails to start x-server

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, nvidia, x-server, proprietary-drivers

On every reboot my Linux Mint deletes `/etc/init.d/xorg.conf` so it doesn't boot the graphical interface, so I have to go to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> every time and copy a backup I have in my home directory using `sudo cp` then run `/etc/init.d/mdm start`.

It basically doesn't find the file. Another solution is running `sudo nvidia-xconfig` every time (but it deletes my presets) or **reinstalling the NVIDIA driver**.

Why is my distro deleting the file on every reboot? Any clue?

OS: Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon; CPU: AMD FX-4300; GPU: NVIDIA GTX 960; RAM: 16 GB

I'm running **NVIDIA 367.44 proprietary drivers**.

Comment: For me the "Xorg -configure" command failed with a segmentation violation. However, it seems it generated (locally in my directory) a "xorg.conf.new" file. When I copied that to "xorg.conf", things seemed to start working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reconfigure `X`:

```
Xorg -configure
```

it will generate a new file `xorg.conf.new` , copy it to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
cp xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

You can create and set up `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf` manually without using `nvidia-xconfig` ; e,g:

```
#/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf

Section "Device"
    Identifier "My GPU"
    Driver "nvidia"
EndSection
```

Or use the following command to create it:

```
mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
echo -e 'Section "Device"\n\tIdentifier "My GPU"\n\tDriver "nvidia"\nEndSection' > /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf
```

Comment: Oh, I'm "a bit" late... I decided to try out Arch Linux in the end, it works great and never had any issues. Can't tell if your solution works, but it probably would, thanks anyway.