# How to install Nvidia driver on Debian and switch between drivers?

Tags: debian, nvidia

I tend to use `nvidia-prime` on Ubuntu to run my intel graphics card instead of NVIDIA, is there a way to use `nvidia-prime` on Debian?

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -v | egrep -i 'vga|3d|nvidia' | grep -i 'nvidia'`

Comment: `kernel modules : nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_340`

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and add the following line:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Update and install drivers:

```
aptitude update
aptitude -r install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') nvidia-kernel-dkms
```

Create an Xorg server configuration file:

```
mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
echo -e 'Section "Device"\n\tIdentifier "My GPU"\n\tDriver "nvidia"\nEndSection' > /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf
```

Reboot

[Debian-wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#jessie)

**Edit**

To switch between driver intel/nvidia run `nvidia-settings` from the terminal and choose the driver.

Comment: after the installation how do i choose which GPU to use?

Comment: after performing this and rebooting my screen stays black like its loading with a "_" on the top of the screen I'm able to access tty1 using ctrl + alt + f1

Comment: @EduardoDíaz see here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314004/153195

Comment: While executing Xorg -configure i get `number of created screens does not match number of detected devices. Configuration failed`  and the server terminates with error (2).